# More succinct event listeners

Tags: jquery, function, event-listener

I have a number of event listeners, that all act slightly differently. What I'm trying to do is make this code more succinct, as it seems like this is a long-winded way of articulating what I'm trying to achieve. Given each function acts after slightly different events have occurred, is that possible, or is this the best I can hope for?

```
function action() {
  var all = $("input, textarea, select");

  all.on("focus, keyup", function() {
    doSomething();
  });

  all.focus(function() {
    doSomethingElse();
  });

  $("input, textarea").keyup(function() {
    doAnotherThing();
  });

  $("select").change(function() {
    doAnotherThing();
    doYetAnotherThing();
  });
}
```

Comment: This question would be better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: An alternative to this is using if statements with `nodeName` and `event.type` inside one `.on('keyup,change,focus', function(){`, but I'm not sure it will result in less code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
function action() {
  var all = $("input, textarea, select");

  all.on("focus, keyup", function(event) {
    doSomething();

    if(event.type == "focus"){
      doSomethingElse();
    }
  });

  $("input, textarea").keyup(function() {
    doAnotherThing(someParams?);
  });

  $("select").change(function() {
    doAnotherThing(someParams?);
    doYetAnotherThing();
  });
}

function doAnotherThing(someParams?){
    //Your code
}
```

Maybe the keyup/change events could be more succint... but currently no idea.